# Why is the first line is skipped

Tags: jq

Why is the first line skipped if I remove `echo "prevent remove first line"`?

```
(echo "prevent remove first line" && find ~/somedir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) | /usr/local/bin/jq -nR \
'{
    "items": [
        inputs |                                     
        inputs as $title |                  
        {
            "title": $title,
        }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should be:

```
find ~/somedir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | /usr/local/bin/jq -nR \
'{
    "items": [      
        inputs as $title |                  
        {
            "title": $title,
        }
    ]
}'
```

From the `jq` man page:

```
 inputs
       Outputs all remaining inputs, one by one.

       This is primarily useful for reductions over a program´s inputs.
```

This implicitly means that every time called, `inputs` reads the next line from stdin. stdin is realized as a pipe, once a line from stdin has been read, it is gone.

When you echo a line before the actual input, then this extra line will be subject to this extra read. Just use `inputs` twice to see the problem coming back:

```
(echo "test" && find ~/somedir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) | /usr/local/bin/jq -nR \
'{
    "items": [
        inputs | inputs |
        inputs as $title |                  
        {
            "title": $title,
        }
    ]
}'
```

---

PS: As [`pmf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110455/why-is-the-first-line-is-skipped/72110653#comment127413019_72110653) pointed out, the whole solution can be simplified to:

```
find ~/somedir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    jq -nR '{items: [{title: inputs}]}'
```

Comment: `inputs` can also be used directly: `jq -nR '{items: [{title: inputs}]}'`

Comment: @pmf I'm formatting `inputs` before using it so I need to store it in $title (just removed the formatting-stuff from the question for brevity). Thanks though! :)

Comment: @tobbe Then here's another shortcut you may find useful: `jq -nR '{items: [inputs as $title | {$title}]}'`